# Excel VBA: A VBA Regular Expression to check the name of a file?

Tags: regex, vba, excel

So basically I writing all of these VBA macros to massage a lot of data. Before that the user should be able to input a date and retrieve the data that they want massaged. The data that needs to be massaged is an Excel Report that is generated each day.

The Format of the filename is: "Year_Month_Day_(RandomlyGeneratedNumbers)_ReportWorkSheet.xls"

In what possible way can I determine the file name? I've already done the easy part of taking the date entered and formatting it. The numbers seem to sit at only six digits long but I have a feeling that it could change. I was thinking that there maybe someway to peer into the directory I'm looking for the xls file and use regular expressions to just match the date that I already formatted to determine which xls file I need. Is there a possible way to do this? Or a different solution?

Just for reference this is the code I have so far:

```
Dim CurrentDateString As String
Dim MonthString As String
Dim DayString As String
Dim YearString As String
Dim FileNameString As String
Dim i As Integer




CurrentDateString = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B2").Value

'Checks to see if the date is in the proper format
If Len(CurrentDateString) = 10 Then


i = InStr(1, CurrentDateString, "/")

MonthString = Mid(CurrentDateString, 1, (i - 1))

i = InStr(4, CurrentDateString, "/")

DayString = Mid(CurrentDateString, 4, (i - 4))
i = InStr(4, CurrentDateString, "/")

YearString = Mid(CurrentDateString, 7, i)

FileNameString = YearString & "_" & MonthString & "_" & DayString & "_" &         "ThisIsWhereTheNumberWouldGo" & "ReportWorkSheet.xls"

 Else
    MsgBox "Current date must have two digits for month and year. Even if its a single digit. For      example January 1st 2014 would be 01/01/2014 NOT 1/1/2014"

  End If
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?? It's not really clear. I don't think this is something you need RegEx for. Are you simply trying to determine if a particular filename already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for any confusion but I was able to figure it out. Regex Wasn't needed. I guess I wasn't clear. Basically I needed to find a filename Based on the date entered. The numbers in the middle of the filename was throwing me off but I didn't really even need to factor that in my solution. I found a way to traverse the directories and then I For Eached through each file and Separated the piece of the filename with just the date then if there was a match. I opened it in excel. Sorry for wasting anyones time :(

```
 FileNameString = YearString & "_" & MonthString & "_" & DayString
Set MyObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder("J:\credit\Christopher Smith\Allegro 8.0 Reports\Post Live")

 For Each myFile In mySource.Files
      DirectoryFileNameString = myFile.Name
   DirectoryFileNameStringTemp = Mid(DirectoryFileNameString, 1, 10)
   If FileNameString = DirectoryFileNameStringTemp Then
         MsgBox "IT WORKS Filename String: " & FileNameString & " = DirectoryFilename: " & 
      Workbooks.Open (myFile.Path)
        'Call another sub to massage data here
 DirectoryFileNameStringTemp
End If
Next
```